# IBM Worklight - Is the .apk encoding provided by Worklight?

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

I just want to know whether my application file (.apk) generated by worklight is encrypted or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Encoding** [is not the same as](http://www.danielmiessler.com/study/encoding_encryption_hashing/) **Encrypting**, which did you mean? Perhaps you meant **Signing**?

- Worklight does not **sign** your .apk, nor even generate it
- The .apk generation - be it signed or not - is done by Google's ADT

  It is the developer's responsibility (= you) to use this tool to produce a signed .apk.
  http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

What you can do regarding **encryption** in Worklight is enabling the `encryptWebResources` option in `application-descriptor.xml`. This will add another layer of protection to your application's *contents* - the web resources.

- search for "`The <security> element`" in [this Information Center topic](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/c_the_application_descriptor.html).